# org.Hibernate.QueryException: not an association for table id

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am new to Hibernate and have been struggling with the hibernate query. I get `org.Hibernate.QueryException: not an association: id`.

This is the query that works correctly and that I was trying to implement. Lets say I have rooms with shelves with boxes. Each box contains an item. I have only the barcode for the box, and I want to get all items that are in that room.

```
select * from items where location_id in 
   (select id from storage where parent_id in
   (select id from storage where parent_id in 
   (select id from storage where barcode like 'some_box_barcode_here')))
```

This is how I organized it in JPA (and I get the exception):

```
DetachedCriteria subCriteriaRoom = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Storage.class, "storageRoom")
            .createAlias("id", "roomId")
            .createAlias("index", "roomIndex")
            .add(Restrictions.eq("roomIndex", barcode));
subCriteriaRoom.setProjection(Projections.property("roomId"));

DetachedCriteria subCriteriaShelf = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Storage.class, "storageShelf")
            .createAlias("id", "shelfId")
            .createAlias("parent", "shelfParent")
            .add(Restrictions.in("shelfParent", subCriteriaRoom));
subCriteriaShelf.setProjection(Projections.property("shelfId"));

DetachedCriteria subCriteriaBox = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Storage.class, "storageBox")
            .createAlias("id", "boxId")
            .createAlias("parent", "boxParent")
            .add(Restrictions.in("boxParent", subCriteriaShelf));
subCriteriaBox.setProjection(Projections.property("boxId"));

Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Item.class, "item");
criteria.createAlias("storage", "storage")
            .add(Subqueries.propertyEq("location", subCriteriaBox));

List list = criteria.list();
```

Some relevant info about the tables:

1.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "storage")
public class Storage implements DataModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "sequence")
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Storage parent;

    @Column(name = "barcode", length = 31, nullable = true)
    private String barcode;
```

2.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "items")
public class Items implements DataModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "sequence")
    private long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) //the foreign key to storage.id
    @JoinColumn(name = "location_id")
    private Storage location;
```

Any hint would be much appreciated.

P.S. The reason I need such a huge query is that right now the rooms are being multiplied in the database because of some bug that won't be fixed for a while.

Comment: why do you create alias for id?

Comment: @Apostolos, shouldn't I? If I don't create the alias I get an exception "Unknown entity: null"

Comment: `alias` is for assosiations with other entities e.g. `parent` as i can see, not simple properties

Comment: `parent` is not an entity, it's a property of `storage`

Comment: yes but still a `Storage` object with `ManyToOne` annotation.

Comment: Oh, I see. But still, without the alias it's still the exception. Any ideas where did I goof?